# Database not updating model in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

So i just started using ASP.NET MVC and i'm really liking it, except i seem to have an odd knack to encounter the most bizarre of errors. I'm making a simple blogging application for myself. I have two simple models: `post` and `comment`. I have a partial view for creating a comment that is embedded in the details view for each post. When i submit the form to update the comment, it goes to my CommentsController's create action, which looks like...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(comment comment)
    {
        comment.date = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            post p = db.posts.Find(comment.post); //I've verified that comment.post is coming in
            if (p.comments == null) p.comments = new List<comment>();
            p.comments.Add(comment);
            db.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Modified; //I'm using this line since that's how its done in the edit actionmethod of the BlogController. I was just updating db.posts.Find(... manually, but that wasn't workign either.
            db.comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Blog", new  { id = comment.post });
        }

        return PartialView(comment);
    }
```

The problem is that while the comment gets added to the database just fine, the post doesn't update. When i examine `p` just before the changes are saved, it's updated, but apparently it never actually commits to database since when i redirect to the Details, those comments aren't there.  Is there anything obviously wrong with my code? Am i missing some basic fundamental of .NET or MVC? Let me know if i need to provide more code or context.

Interesting Note: No matter what, `post.comments` always seems to be null. I set it to an empty list when the post is created, but it still seems to come back null. Not sure if this is just a result of trying to store an empty list or if it has to do with my problem, though. Again, lemme know and i'll stick anything else needed up here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps saving the changes is working fine but you don't see the saved comments to a post because you don't load them when you display the post. You can eager load the comments of a post in your action which displays a post like so:

```
post p = db.posts
    .Include(p1 => p1.comments)
    .Where(p1 => p1.Id == id)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

I also think that you can simplify your Create action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(comment comment)
{
    comment.date = DateTime.Now;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Blog", new  { id = comment.post });
    }

    return PartialView(comment);
}
```

This should work if `comment.post` is the foreign key of a comment to the related post. (Your code looks like this is the case, because of `Find(comment.post)`)

Comment: No, i'm including the comments for each post in the details view with a `@foreach(var item in Model.comments)` ...plus, i know they're not getting saved because next time i try to add a comment, `p.comments` is still null. thanks though.

Comment: I do like the idea of just grabbing the matching comments in the ActionMethod instead of loading from post.comments.  If i can't fix this problem, i'll use that. thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Shields: You don't use lazy loading, right? (Otherwise `p.comments` could not be `null`, it would be at least an empty collection.) If you don't use lazy loading, `p.comments` in your code above will *always* be `null`, no matter how many comments you actually have in the DB. How do you load the comments for the post`s details view? Is `Model.comments` in your foreach loop not null?

Comment: @Slauma i don't think i'm using lazy loading... how would i know? Also, `Model.comments` is null in the post's details view; i'm actually assigning an empty list to it so the view loads :-)

Comment: @Thomas Shields: If your `comments` collection is marked as `virtual` in your `post` model class, you have lazy loading (unless you did disable it explicitely), otherwise not. Try my eager loading example above in your details view action when you load the post. Here are is a brief tutorial about the loading options in EF 4.1: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

Comment: @Slauma ah, i see... got it. thanks! i just stuck this in my details controller: `post.comments = (from c in db.comments
                             where c.post == post.id
                             select c).ToList();`  thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Shields: I see, that works too. But be aware that this makes two roundtrips to the database - one to load the `post` and a second to load the `comments` collection. Eager loading has only one roundtrip - `post` plus `comments` collection will be loaded in one single step. That's the main reason why we have eager loading.

Comment: @Slauma i tried your eager loading example but i'm getting two errors:
"A local variable named 'p' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'p', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"
and 
"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: @Thomas Shields: My fault, we cannot use the same variable for `post p` and in the lambda expression. I will change the lambda variable to `p1` or something in my code above.

Comment: @Slauma ah, got it. just figured it out myself. Code works great: thanks bunches!

Comment: @Thomas Does your solution exactly match what Slauma did? If not, add it as an answer so others can see what you did.

Answer (score 0):

While @Slauma led me to my solution, I'm just posting my final code i used for future reference (thanks @George Stocker)

```
    public ActionResult Create(comment comment)
    {
        comment.date = DateTime.Now;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Blog", new  { id = comment.post });
        }

        return PartialView(comment);
    }
```

and to retrieve comments...

```
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var post = (from p in db.posts
                     where p.id == id
                     select new { p.id, p.title, p.content, p.date, p.tag, comments = (from c in db.comments where c.post == id select c) }).SingleOrDefault();

        post p2 = new post(post.id, post.title, post.content, post.date,post.tag, post.comments.ToList());
        return View(p2);
    }
```